# SQL Server DATE conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         A.Name, AP.PropertyName, APV.Value AS [PropertyValue],
         CONVERT(DATETIME, APV.VALUE, 101) AS [DateValue]
     FROM dbo.Account AS A
     JOIN dbo.AccountProperty AS AP ON AP.AccountTypeId = A.AccountTypeId
     JOIN dbo.AccountPropertyValue AS APV ON APV.AccountPropertyId = APV.AccountPropertyId
                                          AND APV.AccountId = A.AccountId
     WHERE 
         A.AccountTypeId = '19602AEF-27B2-46E6-A068-7E8C18B0DD75'  --VENDOR
         AND AP.PropertyName LIKE '%DATE%'
         AND ISDATE(APV.Value) = 1 
         AND LEN(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(APV.Value), 0 , CHARINDEX( '/',     REVERSE(APV.Value)))) = 4  --ENSURE 4 digit year
     ) AS APV
WHERE 
    APV.DateValue < GETDATE()
```

It results in the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If you comment out the `WHERE APV.DateValue < GETDATE()` clause then there is no error and I get the 300+ rows. When I enable the `WHERE` clause I get the error.

So you are going to tell me my data is jacked up right? Well that's what I thought, so I tried to figure out where the problem in the data was, so I started using `TOP()` to isolate the location. Problem was once I use the `TOP()` function the error went away, I only have 2000 rows of data to begin with. So I put a ridiculous `TOP(99999999)` on the inner `SELECT` and now the entire query works.

The inner `SELECT` returns the same number of rows with or without the `TOP()`.

WHY???

FYI, this is SQL that works:

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    (SELECT TOP(99999999)  
         A.Name, AP.PropertyName, APV.Value AS [PropertyValue],
         CONVERT(DATETIME, APV.VALUE, 101) AS [DateValue]
     FROM dbo.Account AS A
     JOIN dbo.AccountProperty AS AP ON AP.AccountTypeId = A.AccountTypeId
     JOIN dbo.AccountPropertyValue AS APV ON APV.AccountPropertyId = APV.AccountPropertyId
                                          AND APV.AccountId = A.AccountId
     WHERE 
         A.AccountTypeId = '19602AEF-27B2-46E6-A068-7E8C18B0DD75'  --VENDOR
         AND AP.PropertyName LIKE '%DATE%'
         AND ISDATE(APV.Value) = 1 
         AND LEN(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(APV.Value), 0 , CHARINDEX( '/',     REVERSE(APV.Value)))) = 4
     ) AS APV
WHERE 
    APV.DateValue < GETDATE()
```

Comment: down vote?  pretty sure the question is clear, has example?  what is exactly is the anonymous down vote for?

Comment: I see no code of the form `WHERE APV.DateValue < CONVERT( DATETIME,  GETDATE(),101)`.

Comment: i changed my WHERE... sorry, it was test code...  will update post.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your date is such that `APV.VALUE` contains also data that cannot be converted into a date, and should be filtered out using the other criteria?

Since SQL Server can decide to limit the data first using the criteria you have given:

```
APV.DateValue < CONVERT( DATETIME,  GETDATE(),101)
```

And if there is data that cannot be converted into the date, then you will get the error.

To make it more clear, this is what is being filtered:

```
CONVERT( DATETIME, APV.VALUE, 101) AS [DateValue]
```

And if there is any data that cannot be converted into a date using 101 format, the filter using getdate() will fail, even if the row would not be included in the final result set for example because `AP.PropertyName` does not contain `DATE`.

Since you're using SQL Server 2012, using [try_convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) instead of convert should fix your problem

And why it works with top? In that case SQL Server cannot use the criteria from the outer query, because then the result might change, because it might affect the number of rows returned by top

Comment: not the case at all.  Read my entire post, the inner select returns the EXACT same number of rows with or without the TOP...

Comment: Top affects the query plan, because filters can't be moved on the other side of the top. Added than in the answer too.

Comment: Because it tries to filter data using getdate() that it cannot convert to a date, like I said in my answer

Comment: No, your answer is wrong.  I have already tried that, it only works when I put the TOP() in the inner select.

Comment: You used try_convert in the inner select instead of convert and you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is that SQL Server can evaluate the expressions at any time during the query processing -- even before the `WHERE` clause gets evaluated.  This can be a big benefit for performance.  But, the consequence is that errors can be generated by rows not in the final result set.  (This is true of divide-by-zero as well as conversion errors.)

Fortunately, SQL Server has a work-around for the conversion problem.  Use `try_convert()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT( DATETIME, APV.VALUE, 101) AS [DateValue]
```

This returns NULL rather than an error if there is a problem.

The reason why some versions work and others don't is because of the order of execution.  There really isn't a way to predict what does and does not work -- and it could change if the execution plan for the query changes for other reasons (such as table statistics).  Hence, use `try_convert()`.

Comment: what version of SQL server has TRY_CONVERT()?

Comment: @TMcKeown . . . SQL Server 2012+ (which is why I suggest it):  ft.com/en-us/library/hh230993(v=sql.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Because number of records in the table < 999..99. And regarding the error it seems like SQL engine evaluates the WHERE clause after converting to date so you can try this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT  A.Name
  , AP.PropertyName
  , APV.Value AS [PropertyValue]
  , 
  CASE 
    WHEN SDATE(APV.Value)  = 1
    THEN  CONVERT( DATETIME, APV.VALUE, 101) 
    ELSE NULL
  END AS [DateValue]
 FROM dbo.Account AS A
 JOIN dbo.AccountProperty AS AP
   ON AP.AccountTypeId = A.AccountTypeId
 JOIN dbo.AccountPropertyValue AS APV
   ON APV.AccountPropertyId = APV.AccountPropertyId
  AND APV.AccountId = A.AccountId
WHERE A.AccountTypeId = '19602AEF-27B2-46E6-A068-7E8C18B0DD75'  --VENDOR
  AND AP.PropertyName LIKE '%DATE%'
  AND LEN( SUBSTRING( REVERSE(APV.Value), 0 , CHARINDEX( '/',     REVERSE(APV.Value)))) = 4  --ENSURE 4 digit year
    ) AS APV
WHERE APV.DateValue IS NOT NULL  AND APV.DateValue < GETDATE()
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to the number of rows, but to the fact that SQL Server can't move the where clause from the outer query into the inner if there is top, because it could change the results.

Comment: And this is the way this kind of errors can be handled when try_convert is not available (pre-2012), but I'd recommend using try_convert if possible, because it's more easy to understand what it does.